Markdown Post Does Not Show Up on Website
I am attempting to create a new post for my website. For some reason, all that shows up on the live index page is the date. In addition, if I try to access the post itself, I get a 404 notice.  For context, I did not code my website myself; I had two web builders who then taught me how to make minor edits/updates via VSCode & Git Bash. Any help is appreciated!
post is not showing on index page; only the date and it has a broken post link
For the config.yml, I 1) added
timezone: America/New_York,

as I thought perhaps it was an issue where the website couldn't count past 2020; which makes no sense as it clearly shows the date, but no link, title, or image; 2) then I changed
paginate_path: /blog/:num/ 

to
blog/page:num/

as that was the only discrepancy I noticed between my code to Jekyll's. No change.
Then, I just kept renaming blog posts and making sure my markdown code had no typos to no avail. The only change is that if I duplicate a post that already is published, it will show up! But any modified post does not.
I did not change index.html or any post or pagination css, as I could not find anything that would suggest an issue.

Do you have the link to the repo on GitHub?

https://github.com/charadh/charadh.github.io here you are!

The problem is in this markdown file with YAML metadatablock (notice the red Error in user YAML that GitHub displays), specifically this line:
title: 'I'm Published!'

Notice that there are three single quotes on that line? That's not valid YAML.
Either use double quotes:
title: "I'm Published!"

or omit the quotes entirely:
title: I'm Published!


thank you so much! that worked. ok i will be more vigilant about the quotes going forward.
